# String output different when using fprintf vs. printf

Tags: c

I'm in a little bit of a conundrum with something I haven't seen before. In this little bit of code:

```
int start = atoi(startValue);
// print a 32 bit representation of the first number
char num[32];
convertToBinary(start, num, 32);
for (int i = 0; i < numberInRange - 1; i++) {
    fprintf(outputFile, "%s\n", num);
}
printf("%s", num);
```

Now the issue I'm having is that when I have the variable start = -1, my converter correctly sets num to "1111....1" (32 1's). But, when I print it to my file, it is printed as "0111...1" with a leading zero. I put the last printf statement in just to see what it would print, and it correctly printed "1111....1".

A similar thing happens when I start = 8 (these are the two values that have been in my tests. I would assume something strange is happening with other ints as well). My converter sets num to "000.....1000" which is correct. But when I print it to my file it appears as "000.....01111101000" with those added 1's. And again, when I print it to the command line, it appears as the correct implementation.

This might not be something that can be diagnosed from afar, but when I gdb through this section, "num" is correctly represented in each step of the for loop, but it is always printed out with the leading 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: change to `char num[33];`,

Comment: One you thing you should do is to allocate extra char at the end of `num` (for NULL-terminator) and initialize whole array to zeroes, e.g. `num[33] = { 0 };`

Comment: Changing to num[33] didn't do it. I've used this same set up for several other methods, but it's not giving issues.

Good point on the null terminator in general though, that was oversight on my part.

Comment: Why don't you go ahead and post a complete, compilable example that shows the problem.

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the loop (just a single fprintf call). You may have to post your convertToBinary routine.

Comment: Same issue with a single fprintf. I'll try to rig up an example since this is embedded in a rather ugly parser.

Comment: Well, I isolated just that part of my parser and it printed it to file properly. So I'll give it a look and see what it could be.

Comment: Solved it. After I had parsed the file and printed it to a new file (correctly), I was reprocessing my binary strings with atoi(), then converting them back to binary before printing them to another file.